# Where to place the app's splash screen on Xcode UI Builder?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to build my app interface with the interface builder in Xcode. My question is, where to place the splash screen? Is it LuanchScreen.storyboard? or is it the first screen of Main.storyboard?

Comment: LaunchScreen.stroyboard

Answer (score 1):

LuanchScreen.storyboard use it for splash screen design

Main.storyboard for application ui design